# Excel Find Value In Table Based On Name And Change It in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Currently I am working on a project and getting my feet wet with VBA. Right now I need to find a value within a specific table based on the name of an employee and change that value. So in for example the table January:

```
Name;BirthDate;BSN;Salary
P. Decker;19-8-1988;123;$10.000
J. Jackson;20-6-1988;456;$12.000
T. Roberts;18-2-1975;789;$15.000
```

I would like to change salary of J. Jackson.

I am having issues with finding a solution for this. I have found several ways to change a value in a cell, for example with

```
Sub GetValueFromTable()
myValue_1 = InputBox("Fill in name", "Name Employee")
myValue_2 = InputBox("What do you want to change", "What?")
Cells(1, 3) = myValue_1
End Sub
```

But this way I cannot reference the table or put tablenames or anything like that, in that case I could use myValue_2 as "Salary", but the formulas I have found only work with numbers and not with cell references.

Could anyone help me out here so I can get this to work?

Thanks!

---

EDIT:

Alright so after messing aroud for some hours i right now got this:

```
Sub Testnumberounodostreina()
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim cel1 As Range
Dim col As Long
Dim row As Long
Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("January")
Set rng1 = tbl.HeaderRowRange
Set rng2 = tbl.DataBodyRange
Set cel1 = rng1.Find(What:="Salary", LookAt:=xlWhole)
Set cel2 = rng2.Find(What:="J. Jackson", LookAt:=xlWhole)
If cel1 Is Nothing Then
    Beep
Else
    cel1.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    cel2.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    ' --- or ----
    col = cel1.Column
    row = cell.row
    Cells(row, col).Value = "15,000"
End If
End Sub
```

Running this script gives me the following error:

"Run-time error '424':Object required."

This formula is supposed to get the value of the column header and the row based on "Salary" and "J. Jackson", and than it should change the value in that cell to "15.000".

What this code does right now is finding the column header based on "Salary" and returning the value of that column. What it is not doing right is finding the number of the row where "J. Jackson" is. This is why I am getting this error.

Can someone help me to get the value of the row number where "J. Jackson" is?

Thanks

---

EDIT:

Apparently had some typos, it works now!

code is:

```
Sub Testnumberounodostreina()
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim cel1 As Range
Dim cel2 As Range
Dim col As Long
Dim row As Long
Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("January")
Set rng1 = tbl.HeaderRowRange
Set rng2 = tbl.DataBodyRange
Set cel1 = rng1.Find(What:="Salary", LookAt:=xlWhole)
Set cel2 = rng2.Find(What:="J. Jackson", LookAt:=xlWhole)
If cel1 Is Nothing Then
    Beep
Else
    cel1.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    cel2.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    ' --- or ----
    col = cel1.Column
    row = cel2.row
    Cells(row, col).Value = "25,000"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the data in a proper Excel table? Where do you specify the new value?

Comment: You could use the match worksheet function to convert column headers to column numbers.